# Combining regex and linq to split string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

My example code looks like this:

```
string name = "[name1][name2][name3][name4][name5]";

Match match = Regex.Match(name, @"\w+");
string[] _name = new string[5];
int i = 0;

while (match.Success)
{
     _name[i] = match.Value;
     i++;
     match = match.NextMatch();
}
match = null;
```

Can you help me converting the code to 1 line by combining regex and linq?

The result possible looks like: `string[] _name = ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
var result = Regex.Matches("[name1][name2][name3][name4][name5]", @"\w+")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Or instead of `Cast`, you may use `OfType`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx):

> The `OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable)` method returns only those elements in source that can be cast to type `TResult`. To instead receive an exception if an element cannot be cast to type `TResult`, use `Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm. It works perfectly for me :))

Comment: Glad to help. I actually am using `Cast` all the time (old habit), but as you see `OfType` can be safer in some cases. Also, if you plan to port the code to VB.NET, you might prefer `OfType`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function:

```
string name = "[name1][name2][name3][name4][name5]".TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
string[] str = Regex.Split(name, @"\]\[");
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later :))